# Async program flow/show ProgressDialog

Tags: android, multithreading, progressdialog

I have some code that
a) needs about 10..20 seconds to execute
b) returns a value that is used for further processing
c) is called by the user

Thus I created a structure like this:

```
ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(ctx);  
pd.setCancelable(false);
pd.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
pd.setTitle(ctx.getResources().getText(R.string.progress));
pd.setMessage(ctx.getResources().getText(R.string.wait_keygen));
pd.setIndeterminate(true);

returnValue=doSomeDifficultCalculationsHere();

pd.dismiss();
```

Now my problems is: the progress dialogue is not shown, it seems to be blocked by the blocking doSomeDifficultCalculationsHere()-function too.

When I place doSomeDifficultCalculationsHere() into an own thread and do a Thread.join() to wait for result of this function progress dialogue is also not shown because Thread.join() blocks.

When I put the ProgressDialog into the thread I get an exception.

So how else can I solve this problem and let the ProgressDialog be shown when I can't call doSomeDifficultCalculationsHere() really asynchronously because its result is needed for all following steps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do `pd.show()` before `returnValue=doSomeDifficultCalculationsHere();`

Comment: What the f***...you are right, that's missing completely! Thanks!